# Android: Elements pushed off screen

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout containing textviews and imageviews. This activity is going to store user information about a recipe they have created. This means that the information given from the user needs to be long and descriptive. When a large amount of text is entered, this makes all the other elements below get pushed off the screen. How can I make it so the elements do not get pushed off-screen and instead you can just scroll down to them?

My layout before information is entered:

[image]

After information:

[image]

This is the linear layout XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="#606E7F">
<TextView
    android:text="Fill out the fields below and upload an image of your creation! Once finished and satisfied, click the add to log button."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#BFDBFF"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/textVaddinfo"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    android:id="@+id/imageVupload"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@drawable/am_cheese_burger"/>
    <Button
        android:text="Upload Creation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#BFDBFF"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        android:id="@+id/btnUpload"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:onClick="add"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:text="Name of Creation:"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:textColor="#BFDBFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="#BFDBFF"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTName"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Ingredients:"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textVlogingred"
        android:textColor="#BFDBFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="#BFDBFF"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTingred"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="Directions:"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textColor="#BFDBFF"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="#BFDBFF"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTdirection"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Add Recipe!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#BFDBFF"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        android:id="@+id/btnAddLog"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:onClick="logClick"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What would I need to add or change so the elements do not get pushed out of view? would a new layout need to be considerd?

Comment: You should add a ScrollView as the root element

Comment: Thank you, very easy solution